# create category based array from mysql table using php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have retrieve some data from table. form array like

[image]

I want array is..

```
 $subpro[HardDisk] = array (H1000 => 1200,H500 => 700);
    $subpro[Ip] = array (4IP => 400 , 2IP => 200);
    $subpro[Ram] = array (..);
    $subpro[processor] = array (...);
```

php code ..

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
        if(sizeof($subpro[$row['category']]>0) 
array_put_to_position($subpro[$row['category']],$row['rate'], 2,$row['name']);
        else
                        $subpro[$row['category']]=array($row['name']=>$row['rate']);                
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood the question the answer is pretty simple.

```
$subpro = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
  $subpro[$row['category']][$row['name']] = $row['rate'];
}
```

Comment: I have finished it.. thanks for your response.. your answer is correct.. but i finished before submit your answer